# Do I need to define equals and hashCode methods for inheritedClass and Base Class?

Tags: java, equals, hashcode

I am wondering if I should define `equals` and `hashCode` methods in the `Product` class as shown below?

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    // properties 

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return super.equals(other);
    }
}
```

```
public class Product extends BaseEntity {

    // properties   

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return super.equals(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no point overriding those methods to have them do what they did already.

Comment: @khelwood Then how should these classes above be defined?

Comment: Either remove the equals and hashcode methods, or put logic in them that determines equality and hashcode based on the values held by the classes.

Comment: Thanks, but I am asking which approach is true. Then should I remove them?

Comment: It is your code. How you write it depends on how you want your classes to behave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not useful to define `equals` and `hashcode` methods calling their super implementation.
Not defining them at all will use the super implementation.
In that case, they will use the `Object` implementation of hashcode and equals in either case (defining them calling super.equals or super.hashCode or not defining them at all).

Remember to make your implementation of hashcode and equals if you need to use them. The method `equals` is used to check if two objects are logically the same object checking their content. Can be used directly, or not directly when you search for an object in a collection for example. The hashcode is used for the keys of an HashMap and values of an HashSet.

Modern ide helps you creating a correct implementation of those methods depending on the fields that are useful in your context.

Comment: Do you mean that I should not define these methods in the child classes if there is not a special condition of these classes in the child class?

Comment: If you need to adopt exactly the same logic as the superclass you don't need to redefine them in the subclass calling the equivalent method of the superclass. That works for any method, not only equals and hashcode.

Answer (score 1):

@federico To give you correct answer some details,

**equals and hashCode is method from Object class** which is **parent of all class**. equals and hashCode use to define that particular class object is different than other object from same class and find hash value.(which called by other Java collection classes if you using it to store these objects).
Generally we create child class if you have different behavior or fields on top of Parent class. So, child class should have more fields, better to implement equals and hashCode in child class.

There will be **no error if you don't implement** equals and hashCode in child class.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that a product's hashcode is derived from properties unique to a product. We'll also assume that 2 objects are equal if they have the same hashcode. In this scenario:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity {

  public abstract int hashCode();

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object object) {
      return this.hashCode() == object.hashCode();
  }
}

public class Product extends BaseEntity {

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return someValueDerivedFromProductProperties;
  }
}
```

This means that all classes that extend the BaseEntity must define an implementation of hashCode and are considered equal if the returned hashcode values are equal